# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null objec

Tags: null-pointer

When I am trying to access the Opportunity_Item_ID__c: 00k0I00000phfpdQAC in the browser it says "Data Not Available"

"The data you were trying to access could not be found. It may be due to another user deleting the data or a system error. If you know the data is not deleted but cannot access it, please look at our support page."

**Debug Logs:**

```
(336643577)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[233]|oitem|{"Id":"8020I000007aNvcQAY","Ticket_Type__c":"a1u0I0000016NjTQAQ","Quantity":-1.00,"Opportunity_Item_ID__c":"00k0I00000phfpdQAC"}|0x479c32d6
14:56:17.0 (336653750)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[233]
14:56:17.0 (336738849)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[235]|System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
```

Could you please confirm the above error is showing just because the Opportunity item ID is showing null (Data Not Available) ?

**PS**

This info copied from Suneel's comment:

> Class.OTriggerHandler.updateTicketCount: line 235, column 1
>   Class.OTriggerHandler.handleAfterUpdate: line 148, column 1
>   Trigger.OAfterTrigger: line 15, column 1 14:56:17.0
>   (337078434)|FATAL_ERROR|System.NullPointerException: Attempt to
>   de-reference a null object

The above debug logs shows the line number 235 and the code is:

`if(oliMap.get(oitem.Opportunity_Item_ID__c).Member_Count__c) {`

Comment: The exception would have caused to roll back record insert, thus that record does not exists

Comment: Hi Pranay,
Thanks for your reply ! I am new to Salesforce development , could you please let me know what is roll back record insert , you mean to say that opportunity item id record does not exists and that is why it is showing "System.NullPointerException" ?

Comment: without looking at code, it would be very hard to debug, can you edit the question and add relevant code snippets?

Comment: Hi Pranay,
Class.OTriggerHandler.updateTicketCount: line 235, column 1
Class.OTriggerHandler.handleAfterUpdate: line 148, column 1
Trigger.OAfterTrigger: line 15, column 1
14:56:17.0 (337078434)|FATAL_ERROR|System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

The above debug logs shows the line number 235 and the code is 

if(oliMap.get(oitem.Opportunity_Item_ID__c).Member_Count__c) {

Answer (score 2):

For an NPE to happen on this line:

```
if(oliMap.get(oitem.Opportunity_Item_ID__c).Member_Count__c ...) {
```

there are 4 possible causes:

- `oliMap` is null
- `oitem` is null
- the result of `oliMap.get(oitem.Opportunity_Item_ID__c)` is null
- `oliMap.get(oitem.Opportunity_Item_ID__c).Member_Count__c` is null

Guessing, the third is the most likely cause. Review your logic to figure out what should happen in that case. The most basic fix would be to do nothing:

```
if (oliMap.containsKey(oitem.Opportunity_Item_ID__c)) {
    if (oliMap.get(oitem.Opportunity_Item_ID__c).Member_Count__c ...) {
        ...
    }
}
```